# Parse log between datetime range using Python

Tags: python, regex, datetime, parsing, logging

I'm trying to make a dynamic function: I give two datetime values and it could read the log between those datetime values, for example:

```
    start_point = "2019-04-25 09:30:46.781"
    stop_point =  "2019-04-25 10:15:49.109"
```

I'm thinking of algorithm that checks:

1. if the dates are equal:

   - check if the start hour 0 char (09 -> 0) is higher or less than stop hour 0 char (10 -> 1);
   - same check with the hour 1 char ((start) 09 -> 9, (stop) 10 -> 0);
   - same check with the minute 0 char;
   - same check with the minute 1 char;
2. if the dates differ:

   - some other checks...

I don't know if I'm not inventing a wheel again, but I'm really lost, I'll list things I tried:

1.

```
    ...
    cmd = subprocess.Popen(['egrep "2019-04-19 ([0-1][0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9].[0-9]{3}" file.log'], shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    cmd_result = cmd.communicate()[0]
    for i in str(cmd_result).split("\n"):
        print(i)
    ...
```

The problem with this one: I added the values from the example and it couldn't work, because it has invalid ranges like hour 1 chars it creates range [9-0], minute char 0 as well [3-1] and etc.

2.
Tried the following solutions from [The best way to filter a log by a dates range in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12660164/the-best-way-to-filter-a-log-by-a-dates-range-in-python)

Any help is appreciated.

EDIT

the log line structure:

```
    ...
    2019-04-25 09:30:46.781 text text text ...
    2019-04-25 09:30:46.853 text text text ...
    ...
```

EDIT 2

So I tried the code:

```
from datetime import datetime as dt

s1 = "2019-04-25 09:34:11.057"
s2 = "2019-04-25 09:59:43.534"

start = dt.strptime('2019-04-25 09:34:11.057','%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
stop = dt.strptime('2019-04-25 09:59:43.534', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')

start_1 = dt.strptime('09:34:11.057','%H:%M:%S.%f')
stop_1 = dt.strptime('09:59:43.534','%H:%M:%S.%f')

with open('file.out','r') as file:
    for line in file:
        ts = dt.strptime(line.split()[1],'%H:%M:%S.%f')
        if (ts > start_1) and (ts < stop_1):
            print line
```

and I got the error

```
ValueError: time data 'Platform' does not match format '%H:%M:%S.%f'
```

So it seems I found the other problem it contains sometimes non datetime at line start. Is there a way to provide a regex in which I provide the datetime format?

EDIT 3

Fixed the issue when the string appears at the start of the line which causes ValueError and fixed index out of range error when maybe the other values occur:

```
try:
    ts = dt.strptime(line.split()[1],'%H:%M:%S.%f')
    if (ts > start_1) and (ts < stop_1):
        print line
except IndexError as err:
    continue
except ValueError as err:
    continue
```

So now it lists not in the range I provide, now it read the log 
FROM `2019-02-27 09:38:46.229`TO `2019-02-28 09:57:11.028`. Any thoughts?

Comment: Why is this a subprocess?

Comment: @roganjosh this python script is going to run in server and I'm using egrep to filter and basically read file

Comment: Did the 2. work?

Comment: @YevhenKuzmovych sadly not

Comment: @lpkej What was the problem with this solution? I think it should work. And could you show the format of your log?

Comment: @YevhenKuzmovych the problem is that when I put manualy the values in the 2. link Maksym Polshcha's answer it reads the log from 2018-01.... and not in the range I provide

Comment: how about providing a sample of your log file that you are parsing?

Comment: @AzatIbrakov edited the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your edit 2 had the right idea. You need to put exception handling in to catch lines which are not formatted correctly and skip them, for example blank lines, or lines that do not have the timestamp. This can be done as follows:

```
from datetime import datetime

s1 = "2019-04-25 09:24:11.057"
s2 = "2019-04-25 09:59:43.534"

fmt = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f'

start = datetime.strptime(s1, fmt)
stop = datetime.strptime(s2, fmt)


with open('file.out', 'r') as file:
    for line in file:
        line = line.strip()
        
        try:
            ts = datetime.strptime(' '.join(line.split(' ', maxsplit=2)[:2]), fmt)
            
            if start <= ts <= stop:
                print(line)
                
        except:
            pass
```

The whole of the timestamp is used to create `ts`, this was so it can be correctly compared with `start` and `stop`.

Each line first has the trailing newline removed. It is then split on spaces up to twice. The first two splits are then joined back together and converted into a `datetime` object. If this fails, it implies that you do not have a correctly formatted line.