# Export data from log file between time range in Python

Tags: python, parsing, logging

I have been trying to follow the guidelines in this post with some tweaks:
[The best way to filter a log by a dates range in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12660164/the-best-way-to-filter-a-log-by-a-dates-range-in-python)

My log file is like:

```
2020-Oct-12 13:38:57.742759 -0700 : (some text)
(line of text)
(line of text)
2020-Oct-12 13:38:57.742760 -0700 : (some text)
...
2020-Oct-12 13:57:57.742759 -0700 : (some text)
```

I tried these two code snippets but they don't give anything. Is there something wrong with the date-time definition?

```
myfile = open('DIR_extract.log', 'w')
with open('DIRDriver.log','r') as f:
    for line in f:
        d = line.split(" ",1)[0] 
        if d >= '2020-10-12 13:38:57' and d <= '2020-10-12 13:57:57':
            myfile.write("%s\n" % line)
```

and also

```
myfile = open('DIR_extract.log', 'w')
from itertools import dropwhile, takewhile
from_dt, to_td = '2020-10-12 13:38:57', '2020-10-12 13:57:57'
with open('DIRDriver.log') as fin:
    of_interest = takewhile(lambda L: L <= to_td, dropwhile(lambda L: L < from_dt, fin))
    for line in of_interest:
        myfile.write("%s\n" % line)
```

Answer (score 1):

You almost got there.

`d = line.split(" ",1)[0]`  only return the first part of the datetime, eg: `2020-Oct-12`.
That is because your `datetime` format is different than the answer that you linked to. You have space between `date` and `time`.

So to make it work, you need to grasp all date and time part of the line.

```
dt_start = '2020-Oct-12 13:38:57'
dt_end = '2020-Oct-12 13:57:57'
str_time_len = len(dt_start)

with open('DIR_extract.log', 'w+') as myfile:
    with open('DIRDriver.log','r') as f:
        for line in f:
            date_time = line[:str_time_len]
            if dt_start <= date_time <= dt_end:
                myfile.write(line)
```

Assumed that the log file content is

```
2020-Oct-12 13:35:57.742759 -0700 : before
2020-Oct-12 13:38:57.742759 -0700 : start
2020-Oct-12 13:54:57.742759 -0700 : inside
2020-Oct-12 13:57:57.742759 -0700 : end
2020-Oct-12 13:59:57.742759 -0700 : outside
```

The code above gives

```
2020-Oct-12 13:38:57.742759 -0700 : start
2020-Oct-12 13:54:57.742759 -0700 : inside
2020-Oct-12 13:57:57.742759 -0700 : end
```

---

Note that because you use `MMM` format for months so the above code only works for logs that are within a month. Filtering from `Jan` to `Apr` or something like that won't work because `Jan` > `Apr`. You will need to convert those string to `datetime` object.

Moreover, if some log records are multiline, you will need to grasp all lines, not just the line started with datetime.

```py
import re
from datetime import datetime

_start = '2020-Oct-12 13:38:57'
_end = '2020-Oct-12 13:57:57'


dt_fmt = '%Y-%b-%d %H:%M:%S'
dt_reg = r'\d{4}-[A-Za-z]{3}-\d{2}'
dt_start = datetime.strptime(_start, dt_fmt)
dt_end = datetime.strptime(_end, dt_fmt)

str_time_len = len(_start)

with open('DIR_extract.log', 'w+') as myfile:
    with open('DIRDriver.log','r') as f:
        started = False
        for line in f:
            if re.match(dt_reg, line):
                datetime_str = line[:str_time_len]
                dt = datetime.strptime(datetime_str, dt_fmt)
                if not started and dt >= dt_start:
                    started = True
                elif started and dt > dt_end:
                    break

            if not started:
                continue

            myfile.write(line)
            print(line.strip())
```

Assume the log file content is as below:

```
2020-Oct-12 13:35:57.742759 -0700 : before
2020-Oct-12 13:38:57.742759 -0700 : start
2020-Oct-12 13:54:57.742759 -0700 : inside
(line of text)
(line of text)
2020-Oct-12 13:57:57.742759 -0700 : end
2020-Oct-12 13:59:57.742759 -0700 : outside
```

It gives you:

```
2020-Oct-12 13:38:57.742759 -0700 : start
2020-Oct-12 13:54:57.742759 -0700 : inside
(line of text)
(line of text)
2020-Oct-12 13:57:57.742759 -0700 : end
```

Comment: This almost works! Actually, it works except that I didn't realize my situation is a bit more nuanced. I have edited the question. Sometimes, between two datetime lines, there are some text lines with no date. I need to include those two since it falls within the broader datetime range. Makes sense? I'm working towards this now.

Comment: @srkdb I updated the answer to your new case. You just need to check the time only if the line started with datetime.

Comment: Actually, the updated code doesn't include the lines of text in between if it's still within the time range.

Comment: @srkdb please give an example where the updated code doesn’t work.